# Why these ways of defining a function with variable number of arguments fail?

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching

First: I know about the correct way to define a function with variable number of arguments:

```
    Clear[f]
    f[s__] := Plus[s]
    f[1, 2, 3, 4]

(* 10 *)
```

BUT I can't understand why these ideas of mine fail:

My idea #1:

```
    Clear[f]
    f[s_Sequence] := Plus[s]
    f[1, 2, 3, 4]

(* f[1, 2, 3, 4] *)
```

I can't get it why it fails to work. If I understand Mathematica patterns (seemingly, I don't... ;P), any sequence of arguemnts passed to `f` should be matched and named `s`; and then this sequence should be further passed to `Plus`. Yet it doesn't even seem to be matched?

My idea #2:

```
Clear[f]
f[s : (_..)] := Plus[s]
Syntax::sntxf: "(_.." cannot be followed by ")".
```

Or, without the parentheses:

```
Clear[f]
f[s : _..] := Plus[s]
Syntax::tsntxi: "_.." is incomplete; more input is needed.
```

Again, I can't get why it fails to work. The way I understand Mathematica patterns it should work like this: first, `.._` (equivalent to `Repeated[_]`) should match a sequence of any expressions matching `_` (so, actually, a sequence of *any* expressions - so a sequence of 4 integers should qualify?), and then this sequence should be named `s` and further passed to `Plus`. Yet this definition even fails to pass the parser!

Could somebody very kindly explain to me where am I misunderstanding Mathematica patterns and why exactly are those examples failing to work?

Many thanks!

Comment: For your first idea to work, you need to hold an explicit head `Sequence[]`. Such as in `ClearAll[g, f]; SetAttributes[g, SequenceHold]; g[s_Sequence] := Plus[s]; f[s__] := Sequence[s]; g[1, 2]; g[f[1, 2]]`

Comment: @belisarius ...aaand that's why `Head[1,2,3]` gives out errors and not `Sequence`, right?

Comment: Yup. But my knowledge ends there. I can't explain clearly why.

Comment: Two answers, targeting different parts of my question. Sorry, but I can't mark any of them accepted this way :)

Comment: When in doubt, ladies go first

Comment: I honestly don't care anymore whether my answers are accepted or not.  I do hope they're useful though. It wouldn't make sense to repeat kguler's answer unless one is hunting for more rep points.

Comment: @Szabolcs http://english.stackexchange.com/q/226736/2139

Comment: @belisarius and how can I know who's a lady? ;P

Answer (score 7):

Re your `Idea 2`: Both

```
f[s : (_) ..] := Plus[s]
f[1,2,3]
( 6 *)
```

and

```
f[s : _ ..] := Plus[s]
f[1,2,3]
(* 6 *)
```

work as expected.

Without space or parentheses separating `_` (`Blank`) from `..` (`Repeated`), both `(_..)` and `_..` are parsed as `_.` (i.e. `Default`, which represents an argument that can be omitted - see [Default](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Default.html)) followed by `.`  which is bad syntax as indicated by the syntax highlighting:
[image]

Tip: If you double-click on the "_.."  you see that the "_." are grouped together, and the second "." is not parsed with the first ".".

Answer (score 4):

There are a few constructs which are not evaluated in the standard way in Mathematica.  `Unevaluated` and `Sequence` are like this.

When Mathematica evaluates an expression, it will first walk through it and strip out any `Sequence` expressions, leaving only the body.  This is a special step done during evaluation.

```
In[]:=
On[]
f[Sequence[1, 2, 3]]
Off[]

During evaluation of In[12]:= On::trace: On[] --> Null. >>

During evaluation of In[12]:= f::trace: f[Sequence[1,2,3]] --> f[1,2,3]. >>

Out[]= f[1, 2, 3]
```

Other than this special rule, `Sequence` behaves like a normal head.  It behaves like a normal head in pattern matching as well.  Thus `_Sequence` will only match expressions of the form `Sequence[1,2,3]`, but never simply `1,2,3`.  Of course unless we prevent it, `f[Sequence[1,2,3]]` will be transformed to `f[1,2,3]` during the first stage of evaluation, so usually the pattern matcher doesn't even have a chance to see it.

To sum up, it is not technically correct to claim that `Sequence[1,2,3]` *represents* a sequence of expressions in any general context.  What *actually* happens is that expressions of the form `f[Sequence[1,2,3]]` are transformed to `f[1,2,3]` during the first stage of the evaluation procedure.  Pattern matching is unaffected.

Here are some examples demonstrating how `Sequence` works:

```
In[1]:= f[s_Sequence] := {s}

In[2]:= f[1, 2, 3]
Out[2]= f[1, 2, 3]

In[3]:= f[Sequence[1, 2, 3]]
Out[3]= f[1, 2, 3]

In[4]:= f[Unevaluated@Sequence[1, 2, 3]]
Out[4]= {1, 2, 3}

In[5]:= On[]
f[Unevaluated@Sequence[1, 2, 3]]
Off[]

During evaluation of In[5]:= On::trace: On[] --> Null. >>

During evaluation of In[5]:= f::trace: f[Unevaluated[Sequence[1,2,3]]] --> f[Sequence[1,2,3]]. >>

During evaluation of In[5]:= f::trace: f[Sequence[1,2,3]] --> {Sequence[1,2,3]}. >>

During evaluation of In[5]:= List::trace: {Sequence[1,2,3]} --> {1,2,3}. >>

Out[6]= {1, 2, 3}

In[8]:= Attributes[f] = {HoldAll}
Out[8]= {HoldAll}

In[9]:= f[Sequence[1, 2, 3]]
Out[9]= f[1, 2, 3]

In[10]:= Attributes[f] = {SequenceHold}
Out[10]= {SequenceHold}

In[11]:= f[Sequence[1, 2, 3]]
Out[11]= {1, 2, 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the question you compare the patterns `f[s__]` and `f[s_Sequence]`.  Note that these are different patterns:

```
FullForm[f_Sequence]
(* Pattern[f, Blank[Sequence]] *)

FullForm[f[s__]]
(* Pattern[s, BlankSequence[]] *)
```

As the comments point out, `Blank[Sequence]` would be matched by an expression with head `Sequence`, but `Sequence` automatically disappears during evaluations (that's the point of it).

Instead, there is a custom pattern `BlankSequence` which matches things as though they had head `Sequence` (but are in fact simply a comma-delimited sequence of expressions).

Your pattern `f[a,b,c]` is matched by `f[s:BlankSequence]` but not by `f[s:Blank[Sequence]]`.

As the other answer points out, Idea#2 simply contained a syntax error.

Comment: Is there anything new in this answer, that is not already covered in the previous answers & comments (and in the question itself)?

Comment: @gaazkam yes.  The other answer explained why Sequence does not match.  I explained why BlankSequence does match, and showed you how to tease this out for yourself by using FullForm.